# How can I continue to use Accurev with Capistrano 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, accurev

We use AccuRev (and I cannot change that) and have been deploying with Capistrano 2. I need to upgrade to Capistrano 3, but it seems that the Accurev SCM module has been removed. Is there a way I can continue to use AccuRev and deploy with Capistrano 3?

**deploy.rb piece**

```
set :scm, :accurev
```

**Deployment error**

```
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/accurev.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Capistrano3 documentation [says](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/) - there is only git, hg and svn support.

But it should not be so hard to port [old accurev module](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/legacy-v2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/accurev.rb) from Capistrano 2 to Capistrano 3. Some classes changed but core is same - functions have to return proper commands with proper parameters.

You can start from git implementation from [master](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/git.rb) and replace it with AccuRev.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I am using since one year is the following:

**1-** Edit the file capistrano-3.3.5/lib/capistrano/setup.rb and replace

```
load "capistrano/#{fetch(:scm)}.rb"
```

by

```
load "#{fetch(:scm_path, 'capistrano')}/#{fetch(:scm)}.rb"
```

**2-** Add in your config/deploy.rb file

```
set :scm_path, 'path/to/accurev/directory'
```

That will give to capistrano a chance to open the configuration schema of accurev. Note that capistrano v3 changed its syntax, and you may have to modify accurev files (I suggest then to duplicate them in your lib folder).

It's ugly to edit the gem file content directly, but there is no other way here. You can also fork their git and do the modification on your fork if you like.

I have a similar problem because I am using custom-made scm in capistrano. Tried to get them to accept a pull request to add this `scm_path` configuration option since last year but they refuse, saying that they will migrate to something better soon ...